# trouble with recursive function in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a recursive function in python that takes the value of two lists and returns the number of times that a value in the first list is less than the value of the second list that is contained in the same index. At the moment, no matter what I try, the returned value is zero, even when there are values in the first list that are less than the comparable values in the second list. My code is shown below.

```
def compare(list1,list2):
    """takes values from list 1 and compares them to values of the same index in list 2 """
    if list1[0]>=list2[0]:
        z=0
        return z
    if list1[0]<list2[0]:
        z=1
        return z
    x=compare(list1[1:],list2[1:])
    return x
print(compare([1,2,3],[2,1,5])
```

Comment: one of the two if conditions is going to be true and the function will return, so it can never make it to the recursive function call

Comment: Please try to think clearly about your intended logic. In particular, in exactly which circumstances do you want the recursive call to occur? Can the code reach that point? Think about what happens in the cases where `list1[0] > list2[0]`, when `list1[0] == list2[0]` and when `list1[0] < list2[0]`. Can any of these cases result in the recursion? Are there any other possible cases?

Comment: You're wrong. You don't get 0. You get 1, with that call in the last line.

Comment: "and returns the number of times that a value in the first list is less than the value of the second list" Okay, so how is your algorithm intended to work? Hint: are you perhaps intending to *add* the result from a recursive call, to the result of considering the `[0]` elements? Is there anything in your code to cause that to happen?

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich did you not notice the `return` statements?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do. The function either returns 0 or 1. This example call they gave: `compare([1,2,3],[2,1,5]` returns 1 for me. Not 0.

Comment: The other commenters are right in that this problem very much does not require recursion, but please note that this is tail call recursion, which is how loops are done in functional languages.
A hint for OP: tail call recursion loops by exiting the function with another function call, passing state from one call to the next. Can you see where you may be exiting the function too soon? Can you think of what state you want to pass?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely consider adding a safety check to make sure that neither argument is empty:

```py
def compare(list1, list2):
    if not list1 or not list2:
        return 0
    ...
```

Second, as has been pointed out in the comments, your branching statement will *always* direct the program away from the recursive call because you're using `<=` and `>` in the same branch. Exactly one of those branches will *always* execute no matter what, so the recursive call will never be reached. Fix it by using that branch to initialize your accumulator:

```py
def compare(list1, list2):
    if not list1 or not list2:
        return 0
    if list1[0] < list2[0]:
        x = 1
    else:
        x = 0
    ...
```

Third, you're only returning a single value and not accumulating a total anywhere. You want to return `x +`  the recursive call:

```py
def compare(list1, list2):
    if not list1 or not list2:
        return 0
    if list1[0] < list2[0]:
        x = 1
    else:
        x = 0
    return x + compare(list1[1:], list2[1:])
```

If you want to get cute with using the fact that `bool` is just a subtype of `int` and clean up your code a bit:

```py
def compare(list1, list2):
    if not (list1 and list2):
        return 0
    return (list1[0] < list2[0]) + compare(list1[1:], list2[1:])
```

Comment: @person were you helped by my answer?